Problem with Cascade select form, race condition? how to sort this out with htmx
I am creating a form with conditional logic (depend select, cascade select, or whatever is called).
The required behaviour is that when the acommodadion field changes, the accommodation price list updates after, and after that, the accommodation prices update.
The last two select fields trigger a post request each (should be a get request, buts lets forget about that), when the first select field changes (with id_accommodation, -i am using django forms that is why the htmx code is in the div that wraps the select field-) .
The 2 post requests trigger well in the required order as I can see in the console, but the 3rd field is not updating the content as if it was never triggered (but it was). So just to test I added a delay (change from:#id_accommodation delay:2s) in the last field, and it actually works well like this, that means: when the accommodation field changes, the accommodation price list field updates, and then the accommodation prices field finally updates.
Now... this feels to me that is not really a solid way of fixing this and I read the htmx documentation with the "hx-sync" atribute, to put them in queue, Ive actually tried everything, and I am not being able to solve it. I have solved it with vanilla js but the form is bigger and more complex that the fragment that i am posting, and the js is going crazy. I want to solve it with htmx hehe
Any help will be greatly appreciated!
<!-- Accommodation Field -->
                    <div 
                        hx-post="{% url 'get_accommodations_by_school' quotation.id %}?trigger=load" 
                        hx-target="#id_accommodation" 
                        hx-trigger="load, change from:#id_school, change from:#id_city"
                        hx-swap="innerHTML">
                        <label for="{{ form.accommodation.id_for_label }}" class="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700 mb-2">Accommodation</label>
                        {% render_field form.accommodation %}
                    </div>
        
                    <!-- Accommodation Price List Field -->
                    <div 
                        hx-post="{% url 'get_price_lists_by_accommodation' quotation.id %}?trigger=load" 
                        hx-target="#id_accommodation_price_list"
                        hx-trigger="load, change from:#id_accommodation, change from:#id_school, change from:#id_city"
                        hx-swap="innerHTML">
                        <label for="{{ form.accommodation_price_list.id_for_label }}" class="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700 mb-2">Accommodation Price List</label>
                        {% render_field form.accommodation_price_list %}
                    </div>
        
                    <!-- Accommodation Qty Weeks Field -->
                    <div 
                        hx-post="{% url 'get_accommodation_prices_by_price_list' quotation.id %}?trigger=load" 
                        hx-target="#id_accommodation_qty_weeks"
                        hx-trigger="load, change from:#id_accommodation_price_list, change from:#id_accommodation, change from:#id_school, change from:#id_city"
                        hx-swap="innerHTML">
                        <label for="{{ form.accommodation_qty_weeks.id_for_label }}" class="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700 mb-2">Accommodation Quantity Weeks</label>
                        {% render_field form.accommodation_qty_weeks %}
                    </div>

The required behaviour is that when the acommodadion field changes, the accommodation price list updates after, and after that, the accommodation prices update.

This seems so over-engineered. What should happen is that when you change the one select option, everything rerenders in one request and the server is the one that decides what needs to happen; that is the whole point of HTMX, server-sided rendering and thus also server-sided decision making. You could use out of bound swaps to do it. Even if you manage to fix it, with all this cascaded logic going on, are you really still going to understand this code when you look at it 6 months down the line?

Thanks a lot for your response.
It seemed to me that there should be a better way...
I need to figure out how to implement the out of bound swaps to see how that can help.
I appreciate your reponse.
